# Consideration of Two Steps of Up & Down sampling Operation

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

nice to meet you!

I have a one question about Up & Down sampling in CNN.

For example,

### Method 1.

```
conv1 = nn.Conv2Transpose2d(10, 10, kernel_size = 3, stride = 2, padding = 1 ) 
conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 5, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1 )

input = torch.randn(1,10,30,30) 
h = conv1(input)   # h.shape >>> (1,10,60,60)
output = conv2(h)  # output.shape >>> (1,5,60,60)
```

---

### Method 2.

```
conv1 = nn.Conv2Transpose2d(10, 5, kernel_size = 3, stride = 2, padding = 1 ) 
input = torch.randn(1,10,30,30) 
output = conv1(input)  # output.shape >>> (1,5,60,60)
```

---

So, what is best method ?? 
To my understanding, Method 2 seems reasonable.

Comment: The main reason to use a `convolution` layer after a `transpose convolution` is to remove Checkbox artefacts that may be introduced.

Comment: Sorry, what is Checkbox artefacts ...? I did search that on google but nothing ... I couldn't found. Please, give me a link?

Comment: The generated image will have tiny boxes, that reduce the clarity and an expected "natural" look.

Comment: They are also called `checkerboard` artifacts